# Woocommerce product custom review tab hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, product, review

Hello I am creating a woocommerce wordpress website and I'm trying to replace the default reviews display with our own integration from Bazaarvoice. so I calledback the reviews tab to display my own function that gets the model number of the product and puts it into the code to display the bazaarvoice review display. The code works except that `global $product` doesn't work because I don't really know how to use hooks. I know the add_action for function bv_reviews_tab isn't correct so I'm not really sure what I am supposed to be putting there. I have been racking my head all day

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_renam_tabs', 98 );
function woo_renam_tabs( $tabs ) {
$tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Product Data' );    // Rename the additional information tab
$tabs['additional_information']['callback'] = 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab';
$tabs['reviews']['callback'] = 'bv_reviews_tab';

return $tabs;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', ' bv_reviews_tab' );
function bv_reviews_tab( ) {

global $product;

if ( $product->is_type('simple' ) ) {

$model = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_model_number', true ) );
   
}
elseif ( $product->is_type('variable' ) ) {
    // Get childIDs in an array
    $children_ids = $product->get_children();

    // Loop
    foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
        // Get product
        $product = wc_get_product( $child_id ); 

        $model = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $child_id, '_model_number', true ) );
    }
    }
    ?>
   <div 
    data-bv-show="reviews"
  data-bv-product-id= "<?php echo $model; ?>"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   >
  </div>
  <?php
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `add_action` in this case. The `callback` value given in the `woo_renam_tabs` function will trigger your custom function. Remove that `add_action` line and you should be good to go. global $product will also work.

Also, you will need to give a title to the reviews tab and ensure reviews tab is enabled in the WooCommerce >Settings > Products

This is the code that I have tested and is working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_renam_tabs', 98 );
function woo_renam_tabs( $tabs ) {
$tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Product Data' );    // Rename the additional information tab
$tabs['additional_information']['callback'] = 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab';
$tabs['reviews']['title'] = __( 'Reviews' ); ;
$tabs['reviews']['callback'] = 'bv_reviews_tab';
return $tabs;
}

function bv_reviews_tab() {
global $product;
 ?>
<div data-bv-show="reviews">
    <?php echo $product->get_name();?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: this didn't do anything for me. I started without the add_action but the only issue that's happening is that it's not recognizing global $product for some reason because it's not getting any value from it. I'm trying to get a custom metafield (model number) not the name and I know the function works because I used it before.